# Lit Element - multiple properties in one decorator

Tags: lit-element

I'm reading some Lit Element codes from internet, and I see they declare multiple properties in a single decorator:

```js
@property()
rowData: string = '';
rowDataCount: number = 0;
```

I'm wondering how it behaves and in this case how can I use type converter:

```js
@property({ type: <String or Number here????> })
rowData: string = '';
rowDataCount: number = 0;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot apply the decorator to two members in one go.

I am afraid you were mislead by the two members being right underneath each other. The `@property()` decorator only applies to the `rowData` member.
The following two snippets are equivalent:

```js
// snippet A: no visual separation
@property()
rowData: String = '';
rowDataCount: number = 0;
```

```js
// snippet B: with blank lines for visual separation
@property()
rowData: String = '';

rowDataCount: number = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I'm clear now :)